# Seamlessly playing sound effects pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I'm creating a car game, everything works completely fine except I can't get the sound effect to work properly. I'd like it to play when the car is moving, and fade when it stops, I have a short clip of an engine noise. When I run the code, the noise is very staggered and jittery. What I'm after is for the clip to play over itself and then the first to stop. This would cause a noise that stops when the button isn't pressed. Here's what I tried:

```
carSound = pygame.mixer.Sound('car.mp3')
effect = 0

while True:

   keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[K_w] or keys[K_UP]:
        effect += 1
        carSound.play()
        if effect >= 10:
            carSound.stop()
            effect = 0
```

I'm not at all used to doing this and don't know how to proceed. So how would I get the sound effect to play properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, using events would be more suitable. When the key is being pressed (keyDown-event), just start the sound playing infinitely with `carSound.play(-1)` and then stop it on key release (keyUp-event) with `carSound.stop()`.